# Search multi-dimensional array for key then find specific key in same array

Tags: php, gmail-api

I finally broke ground with the [Gmail API in PHP](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) but I am having trouble getting the From, Subject and Time from the headers

I have an array that looks like this but goes on and on:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Google_Service_Gmail_MessagePartHeader Object
        (
            [name] => Subject
            [value] => My Subject
            [modelData:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [processed:protected] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [1] => Google_Service_Gmail_MessagePartHeader Object
        (
            [name] => From
            [value] => John Doe
            [modelData:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [processed:protected] => Array
                (
                )

        )
```

In a nutshell I just need a way to search the array for when `['name'] => 'Date'` then I need store what is in the `['value']` key in a variable so I can echo it out later. Should I use something like [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) for this or is there a better way?

Comment: `Array_search` won't help. Just loop over the array and check `name` property.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about header order (99% of clients won't) you could transform it from:
List of (Name, Value) to Map/Dict of Name => List<Value>.  For most headers you care about there will only be one value in the list but that would make getting from/subject/to headers trivial.

In python it would be:

```
headers = {}
for header in header_list:
  if header['name'] not in headers:
    headers['name'] = []
  headers['name'].append(header['value'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to iterate through array and check `name` property value:

```
$date_value = '';
foreach ($headers as $header) {
    if ('Date' == $header->name) {
        $date_value = $header->value;
        break;
    }
}
var_dump($date_value);
```

Here `$headers` is your array.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Grab only those elements of the array where the items ["name"] key is Date  
$b=array_filter($array,function($x){if ($x["name"]=="Date") return true; else return false;});
// Now $b is an array containing all elements of $a that are dates

// Then, echo each one of $b's "value"  
array_walk($b,function($k,$v){echo $b[$k]["value"];});
```